# (PLSQL) What is the simplest expression to test for a changed value in an Oracle on-update trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Here is a boolean expression that does the trick:

```
nvl(:new.location != :old.location, (:new.location is null) != (:old.location is null))
```

But I would like to think there was a simpler expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decode(:old.location, :new.location, 1) is null
```

**edit:** It might be more clear to say:

```
decode(:old.location, :new.location, null, 1) = 1
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of your first version. It's unfortunate that it isn't very obvious what it does, but with enough use, I suppose it could become idiomatic. It's simple enough that it could easily be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

These shorter methods all have several disadvantages.
They are slow, unintuitive, potentially buggy (avoid magic values whenever possible),
and more proprietary than normal conditions like AND/OR/IS NULL/IS NOT NULL.

NVL, DECODE, COALESCE, etc., can be more expensive than you think.

I've seen this lots of times in several different contexts, here's a simple example:

```
--Shorter method: Takes about 0.45 seconds
declare
  j number;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 1000000 loop
    j := i;
    if nvl(i <> j, (i is null) <> (j is null)) then
      null;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/

--Normal method: Takes about 0.25 seconds
declare
  j number;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 1000000 loop
    j := i;
    if i <> j or (i is null and j is not null) or (i is not null and j is null) then
      null;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I recommend you spend the extra second to type it the logical way.  Your code will look better and run faster.

Comment: I don't know why but in our environment 11g R1 it's in opposite way. The first nvl-solution takes avg 0,125 seconds and the second solution takes 0,235 seconds. And if I comment out "j := 1" then both are about 0,05 seconds faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an overloaded package function like this:

```
package p is

    function changed (p_old varchar2, p_new varchar2) return voolean;
    function changed (p_old number, p_new number) return voolean;
    function changed (p_old date, p_new date) return voolean;

end;
```

Then just call it in your triggers:

```
if p.changed(:old.location,:new.location) then ...
```

Alternatively you can just do this:

```
if nvl(:old.location,'£$%') != nvl(:new.location,'£$%') then ...
```

Of course, you have to pick a value that could **never** be a real location, which may be tricky in some cases.  For VARCHAR2 you could pick a value that's too long for the column size (unless that happens to be 4000).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you only want the trigger to fire at all if the value has changed?  If so, you are best to use this syntax when creating the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DepartTrigger BEFORE UPDATE OF location ON Department
```

Comment: ... although you still need to check for a change as "update department set location = location" would fire the trigger.