# How should I deal with null parameters in a PL/SQL stored procedure when I want to use them in comparisons?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure with a parameter `name` which I want to use in a `where` clause to match the value of a column i.e. something like

```
where col1 = name
```

Now of course this fails to match `null` to `null` because of the way `null` works.  Do I need to do

```
where ((name is null and col1 is null) or col1 = name)
```

in situations like this or is there a more concise way of doing it?

Comment: See a duplicate question and its answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014620/oracle-pl-sql-null-input-parameter-where-condition

Comment: @RuslansUralovs This is not a duplicate. This question is about comparing nulls, the other is about excluding the parameter entirely when it is null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`decode`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function in the following fashion:

```
where decode(col1, name, 0) is not null
```

Cite from SQL reference:

> In a DECODE function, Oracle considers
>   two nulls to be equivalent.

Comment: That's something I never knew about `DECODE`. But shouldn't that be `where decode(col1,name,0,1) = 0` or something?

Comment: @Adam Hawkes in your example you've specified the 4-th argument of `decode` - default value if no matches have been found. If the 4-th argument is not specified `decode` returns `null`, hence our code samples are identical if we concern the author's question: compare `null` values.

Answer (score 6):

I think your own suggestion is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

What you have done is correct.  There is a more concise way, but it isn't really better:

```
where nvl(col1,'xx') = nvl(name,'xx')
```

The trouble is, you have to make sure that the value you use for nulls ('xx' is my example) couldn't actually be a real value in the data.

Answer (score 4):

If `col1` is indexed, it would be best (performance-wise) to split the query in two:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col1 = name
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   name IS NULL AND col1 IS NULL
```

This way, `Oracle` can optimize both queries independently, so the first or second part won't be actually executed depending on the `name` passed being `NULL` or not.

`Oracle`, though, does not index `NULL` values of fields, so searching for a `NULL` value will always result in a full table scan.

If your table is large, holds few `NULL` values and you search for them frequently, you can create a function-based index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_col1__null ON mytable (CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 END)
```

and use it in a query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col1 = name 
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 END = CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 END
```

Comment: The optimizer won't know if the parameter (which becomes a bind variable) is null or not, so it will run both queries - probably slower as it will likely involve a full table scan AND an indexed read (or second full table scan!)

Comment: The optimizer won't, but the query engine will. The second query will show up in the plan but won't be really executed. Just try it.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it the way you have it.  It's more intuitive, less buggy, works in any database, and is faster.  The concise way is not always the best.  See [(PLSQL) What is the simplest expression to test for a changed value in an Oracle on-update trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678436/plsql-what-is-the-simplest-expression-to-test-for-a-changed-value-in-an-oracle/3682004#3682004)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE paramater IS NULL OR column = parameter;
```