# How to check for null/empty/whitespace values with a single test?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'd like to write a SELECT statement that uses just one test to return columns with no value (null, empty, or all spaces).

I thought this would work:

```
SELECT column_name from table_name WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%_%';
```

But this does not work for NULL values.

Of course I can add

```
OR column_name IS NULL
```

and it will work, but I'd like a way that uses a single test.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042496/how-should-i-deal-with-null-parameters-in-a-pl-sql-stored-procedure-when-i-want-t/4042572#4042572

Comment: Is it not desirable to have multiple tests? i.e. more granularity = better feedback to users about how to correct data.

Comment: @onedaywhen: In general it may be better to have more granularity, but I'm working with an existing code base and I want to to mimic the existing code structure as closely as possible.  The current code does only one test, so I was looking for a solution that also had only one test.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Functionally, you should be able to use

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM table_name
 WHERE TRIM(column_name) IS NULL
```

The problem there is that an index on COLUMN_NAME would not be used.  You would need to have a function-based index on TRIM(column_name) if that is a selective condition.

Comment: Note for T-SQL users: there is no TRIM, you'll need LTRIM or RTRIM.

Comment: Since **SQL Server 2017** there is a TRIM function. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql)

Comment: @EhMann365 this question is about Oracle, not Sql Server.

Comment: RTRIM(LTRIM(column_name)) - For Microsft SQL Users.

Comment: nice little trick, works well as equivalent to String.IsnullOrWhiteSpace in c#.

Comment: In Sql Server TRIM(column_name)  returns empty string '', not NULL. Other answers support both empty string and NULL

Comment: For those who are expecting to cover all cases: TRIM doesn't work for new line characters

Comment: Use TRIM(ISNULL(column_name, '')) = ''

Comment: This will not work with empty string

Comment: @Tanu - Define "not work".  Oracle considers the empty string to be NULL so trim(NULL) would still be NULL.  Other databases would have different semantics but the question is tagged for Oracle.

Comment: @JustinCave on using select * from table where trim(columnname) is not NULL, gives me the data where column is not null and all the empty strings as well. I tried it on MySQL database.

Comment: @Tanu - MySQL is very different from Oracle.  MySQL treats the empty string as distinct from NULL.  Oracle was not.  The question was tagged for Oracle so the answer works for Oracle.  Each database will have a slightly different answer because each dialect of SQL has slightly different semantics, different databases have different built-in functions, etc.

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT column_name from table_name
WHERE RTRIM(ISNULL(column_name, '')) LIKE ''
```

`ISNULL(column_name, '')` will return '' if column_name is NULL, otherwise it will return column_name.

*UPDATE*

In Oracle, you can use `NVL` to achieve the same results.

```
SELECT column_name from table_name
WHERE RTRIM(NVL(column_name, '')) LIKE ''
```

Comment: actually this still doesn't work in Oracle, Oracle treats empty strings as NULL so you may not have a clause of "not like  ''" since it's comparing against a null value

Comment: Wouldn't I want LIKE '' instead of NOT LIKE '' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, misread the original question as wanting everything that has a value. But as tanging pointed out, it doesn't look like this will work in Oracle.

Comment: Since I'm using Oracle, it looks like I can use WHERE TRIM(col) IS NULL and that will take care of null, blank, and whitespace values.

Comment: Obviously, the first part is missing a parentheses, it should be: `WHERE RTRIM(ISNULL(column_name, '')) LIKE ''`

Answer (score 27):

The NULLIF function will convert any column value with only whitespace into a NULL value. Works for T-SQL and SQL Server 2008 & up.

```
SELECT [column_name]
FROM [table_name]
WHERE NULLIF([column_name], '') IS NULL
```

Comment: A good answer would contain an explanation of the code, and why it was written this way. I recommend you update your answer :-)

Comment: Whats the point of this? It would be more efficient to just set it to [column_name] LIKE ''

Comment: It needs TRIM to support multiple white spaces

Comment: Testing on SQL Server 2017, this does work for multiple white spaces without TRIM.  It doesn't make sense to me, because according the documentation NULLIF should return NULL only if the two expressions are equal, and a string of spaces does not usually equal an empty string. (I only tested for spaces, not tabs, newlines, or other whitespace characters.)

Comment: @Jovie SQL Server sometimes ignores trailing whitespace, read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically

Comment: And this is much more faster than trim :)

Answer (score 9):

While checking `null or Empty` value for a column, I noticed that there are some support concerns in various Databases.

*Every Database doesn't support* `TRIM` *method.*

Below is the matrix just to understand the supported methods by different databases.

The TRIM function in SQL is used to remove specified prefix or suffix from a string. The most common pattern being removed is white spaces. This function is called differently in different databases:

- **MySQL:** `TRIM(), RTRIM(), LTRIM()`
- **Oracle:** `RTRIM(), LTRIM()`
- **SQL Server:** `TRIM(), RTRIM(), LTRIM()`

***How to Check Empty/Null/Whitespace :-***

> Below are two different ways according to different Databases-

The syntax for these trim functions are:

1. **Use of Trim to check-**

   `SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE TRIM(LastName) IS NULL`
2. **Use of LTRIM & RTRIM to check-**

   `SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)) IS NULL`

*Above both ways provide same result just use based on your DataBase support. It Just returns the `FirstName` from `UserDetails` table if it has an empty `LastName`*

**Hoping this will help others too :)**

Comment: WITH t as ( select ' ' c union all select '' c union all select NULL) SELECT * FROM t WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(c)) IS NULL; 
didn't returned 3 records on SQL server

Comment: Why would both L & RTRIM be needed? Wouldn't only one of the functions suffice to check if column is empty?

Answer (score 6):

This phpMyAdmin query is returning those rows, that are NOT null or empty or just whitespaces:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE NOT ((`column_name` IS NULL) OR (TRIM(`column_name`) LIKE ''))
```

if you want to select rows that are null/empty/just whitespaces just remove NOT.

Answer (score 3):

Use below query and it works

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name where isnull(column_name,'') <> ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Although @MerrickPlainview answer seems close and small, the full answer (to also deal with white space as the OP asked for) would be this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE NULLIF(TRIM(column_name), '') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

What I use for `IsNotNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace` in T-SQL is:

```
SELECT [column_name] FROM [table_name]
WHERE LEN(RTRIM(ISNULL([column_name], ''))) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This covers null and empty spaces

```
TRIM(ColumnName) <> ''
```

Comment: Caveats: You can't negate this using "=". Such skips nulls. I have yet to find a short way to negate it. Also, some RDBMS don't implement TRIM(), but you can use RTRIM() instead (right trim).

I wish to create a user-defined function similar to C#'s IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), but that's allegedly hard on performance if the column passed as a parameter is indexed.  I wish the SQL committee would add a comparable function to the SQL standard, as this is a very common need.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me. Here is what finally worked for me:

I am not sure why it would not work with `< 1`, but for some reason `< 2` worked and only returned records whose field is just blank.

```sql
select [columnName] from [tableName] where LENGTH(columnName) < 2 ;
```

I am guessing whatever script that was used to convert data over has left something in the field even though it shows blank, that is my guess anyways as to why the `< 2` works but not `< 1`.

However, if you have any other values in that column field that are less than two characters then you might have to come up with another solution. If there are not a lot of other characters then you can single them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this. This works for me, when you want to fetch both null value and another condition (i.e) my query should return the rows where columnname should be null and should have the word 'questiontext'.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE (('columnname' IS NULL) OR (TRIM('columnname') LIKE 'questiontext'))
```

Here, my 'columnname' should be equal to 'questiontext'.

Answer (score 0):

> select * from table_name where column_name NOT Like '%_%' or
> column_name is null

Answer (score -3):

As in Oracle you can use NVL function in MySQL you can use IFNULL(columnaName, newValue) to achieve your desired result as in this example

```
SELECT column_name from table_name WHERE IFNULL(column_name,'') NOT LIKE '%_%';
```

Answer (score -6):

you can use

```
SELECT [column_name] 
FROM [table_name]
WHERE [column_name] LIKE '% %' 
OR [column_name] IS NULL
```

Comment: This just returns any record with a space or NULL